# Shortcut @ key is not functioning properly

Tags: shortcut-keys

Please help someone, I am new to Ubuntu.I bought a new laptop with ubuntu in it and `@` key is not functioning and gets written on pressing `"` key. please help asap.

Comment: Add more details about your system

Answer (score 1):

That is because you've your keyboard defined to a different layout (german for example).

In order to change your keyboard layout, go to DASH and search for "keyboard". Open it and change your keyboard layout accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Linux is actually using the right keyboard (and Mac), Windows actually does something which instead  of typing @ like "Shift+2" it replaces "Shift" with "Ctrl+Alt". Yes, this even happens on the layout of your own keyboard!